# Missing 'libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl' when try to authentication user by JWT token on docker container - .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, azure, docker, jwt

I'm using Angular 10 client with .net core 3.1 backend. Authentication is resolved by Azure Active Directory.

Everything on my local environment works perfectly, but when I published it in docker image hosted in kubernetes. Adventure was began...

When I trying to get information from controller protected by `[Authorize]` I have got response like:

`Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"` with code `401`

When I fetch more details, logs show me:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: 'HIDE', InternalId: 'HIDE'. , KeyId: HIDE '. kid: 'HIDE'. Exceptions caught: 'System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at Interop.CryptoInitializer.EnsureOpenSslInitialized(
 at Interop.CryptoInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Interop.CryptoInitializer.Initialize(
 at Interop.Crypto..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Interop.Crypto.DecodeRsaPublicKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 buf
 at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAOpenSsl.ImportRSAPublicKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Int32& bytesRead
 at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509Encoder.BuildRsaPublicKey(Byte[] encodedData
 at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509Encoder.DecodePublicKey(Oid oid, Byte[] encodedKeyValue, Byte[] encodedParameters, ICertificatePal certificatePal
 at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPublicKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints
 at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPublicKey(X509Certificate2 certificate
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PublicKey(
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SupportedAlgorithms.IsSupportedAlgorithm(String algorithm, SecurityKey key
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.IsSupportedAlgorithm(String algorithm, SecurityKey key
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying(SecurityKey key, String algorithm
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(Byte[] encodedBytes, Byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, String algorithm, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) '. token: 'HIDED'. at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

Some code:

docker image (I tried also bionic):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Startup.class

```
          services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:Instance") + GetKeyOrDefault("AD:TenantId");
                        options.Audience = "api://" +  GetKeyOrDefault("AD:ClientId");

                        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
                     

                        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[]
                        {
                            options.Audience
                            
                        };
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        
                        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
                        
                        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed += context =>
                        {
                            _logger.Error(context.Exception?.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Principal?.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Scheme?.ToString());

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                        
                        options.Events.OnMessageReceived += context =>
                        {
                            _logger.Error(context.Token?.ToString());

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                        
                        options.Events.OnTokenValidated += context =>
                        {
                            _logger.Error(context.Properties?.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Options?.ClaimsIssuer?.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Options?.ForwardAuthenticate?.ToString());

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                        
                        _logger.Information($"JWT | {options.Authority} | {options.Audience} | {options.ClaimsIssuer}");
                    },
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.TenantId = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:TenantId");
                        options.ClientId = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:ClientId");
                        options.Instance = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:Instance");
                        options.Authority = "api://" +  GetKeyOrDefault("AD:ClientId");
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        
                        _logger.Information($"JWT | {options.Authority} | {options.TenantId} | { options.ClientId } | {options.Instance} |  | {options.ClaimsIssuer}");

                        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed += context =>
                        {
                            _logger.Error(context.Exception.ToString());

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                        
                        options.Events.OnMessageReceived += context =>
                        {
                            _logger.Error(context.Token.ToString());

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                        
                        options.Events.OnAccessDenied += context =>
                        {
                            _logger.Error(context.Properties.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Options.ClaimsIssuer.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Options.ForwardAuthenticate.ToString());
                            _logger.Error(context.Options.AccessDeniedPath.ToString());

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };

                    })
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.ClientSecret = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:ClientSecret");
                        options.ClientId = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:ClientId");
                        options.Instance = GetKeyOrDefault("AD:Instance");
                        options.TenantId =  GetKeyOrDefault("AD:TenantId");
                    })
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(_configuration.GetSection("PayAdmin:DownstreamAP"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

HIDE - encrypted fileds

Comment: Please use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have got it :-).

It was caused by version of System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl library. In my case, paket manager automatically (for dependency reference) upgraded my library to System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 5.0.0 version, so my docker image doesn't not have proper version of SDK, so all operations related to using openssl were failed.

In my case solution was revert to System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.7.0 (I must put this information hard into paket dependencies)